# How to create a mac app from python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, bundle

I currently have a python application that runs perfectly from the CLI and when I run it from an IDE. I want to make it into an application that will launch in 1 click from any mac computer. (Like any desktop application). Ideally, I can send someone the file, they do a simple install, then the program works. I have tried using platypus (works great for 1 file programs) and other methods of bundling apps. But none of them seem to work as the program is kinda complex.

Program Requirements:

- Python3
- Python Libraries tkinter, socket, threading, PIL etc
- ~8 individual python files (controlled by 1 main menu)
- Lots of images

I would like to have an install process, where you click next a bunch of times and agree to things, but if this isn't possible I can live without it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PyInstaller to build your package. I do not think they have an actual installer, but you could build your own GUI installer by using some CMD commands and something like tkinter.

Comment: This works great, but I have run into issues adding multiple images. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Yep, so what I usually do is create a sub directory which stores all dependencies for your app. You need to add it to the analysis section of the spec sheet. Read the adding data section on [this page](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) and that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I have used py2app for this in the past (https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This article does a good job of explaining how to use it (https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/)

Basically you install the library and create a setup.py file that looks something like this

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Sandwich.py']
APP_NAME = "SuperSandwich"
DATA_FILES = []

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile': 'app.icns',
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': APP_NAME,
        'CFBundleDisplayName': APP_NAME,
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': "Making Sandwiches",
        'CFBundleIdentifier': "com.metachris.osx.sandwich",
        'CFBundleVersion': "0.1.0",
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': "0.1.0",
        'NSHumanReadableCopyright': u"Copyright © 2015, Chris Hager, All Rights Reserved"
    }
}

setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```